# How to upload an android aar library to maven central with other aar dependencies?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I wrote an aar library named LibA, it depends my aar libs LibB and LibC.
LibB and LibC has already uploaded into maven, but my LibA cannot build by the same Gradle task at this time, because I have to wait about 20 minutes for Maven Central sync with Nexus.
I want deploy LibA, LibB and LibC at same task, how can I do?

here is the gradle dependency of LibA:

```
dependencies {
    compile ("group.LibB:version@aar")
    compile ("group.LibC:version@aar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the many gradle maven publish helpers.

I work on [gradle-fury](https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury) which you may to want check out. It definitely works for direct publish to sonatype oss. With it, you can publish the aar to maven local using

then in the build scripts for everything you'll need to reference the `mavenLocal()` repository to resolution

LibB

`gradlew install`

LibC

`gradlew install`

LibA

`gradlew install`